# How to show Tab Bar in a component class having no tabs open in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**My Question is when the app launch there is a screen open in which there are 5 tabs showing but no tabs is open . screen have its own UI and Tabs have its own UI**

Comment: Are you using react-navigation?

Comment: I'm using React Navigation Using Tabs

Answer (score 1):

I cant say I fully understand your question, however I am going to show you a simple way to use react-navigation tab bar.
Create a `router.js` file to define your routing.

```
//router.js
import React from 'react';
import {
    createBottomTabNavigator,
    createAppContainer,
    createStackNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

//Screens
import Home from '../screens/Home';
import TabTwo from '../screens/TabTwo';
import AStackScreen from '../screens/AStackScreen';


const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: Home,
    TabTwo: TabTwo
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
            if (navigation.state.routeName === 'Home') {
                return <Icon name='ios-locate' size={30} color={tintColor} />
            } else if (navigation.state.routeName === 'TabTwo') {
                return <Icon name='ios-heart' size={30} color={tintColor} />
            }
        },
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#ff4949',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            style: { backgroundColor: '#000', paddingTop: 5 }
        },
    })
});

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Root: TabNavigator,
        AStackScreen: AStackScreen
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerTitle: 'Whatever',
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                elevation: 0,
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: '#999',
                fontSize: 16,
            },
            headerBackTitleStyle: {
                color: '#999',
                fontSize: 14
            }
        })
    }
)

export const MainNavigator = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

In your `App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { MainNavigator } from './src/router.js';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <MainNavigator />;
    }
}
```

As you can see we have a first screen which holds the tabBar with each screen of the tabs within the tabs. I have added another screen to a stackNavigator which allows you to navigate away from the tabs to a stack screen. It all depends on your needs. You can just use only tabs or use a combination of tabs and stack navigators.

Comment: Hii LordKiz I do this what you say also now i want  my App.js contain GridView too..

Comment: You have to add the screens in your router.js configuration. Create a GridView screen and put it in your home screen or any screen you want.

Comment: let me explain you again , Once my app starts App.js Screen launch in which i have to show  GridView and at bottom there are 5 Tabs name "Index" , "Favourite" , "Buying" , "Selling" , "Preview"  and these all 5 tabs have their own views or classes

Comment: Good. For the first tab, maybe Index, define a screen GridView.js and put it in the tab you want it in. Example: 
`const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Index: GridView,
    TabTwo: TabTwo
},`

Comment: these 5 tabs have different functionality and gridview is default having tabs at bottom , gridview is not launch from any of these tabs.

Comment: I'll have to see your setup to understand what you want.

Comment: Once my app starts App.js Screen launch in which i have to show GridView and at bottom there are 5 Tabs name "Index" , "Favourite" , "Buying" , "Selling" , "Preview" and these all 5 tabs have their own views or classes , this gridview is not called by any of these Tabs also when i press Index Tab than index class launch in which their is a back button when i press this button than again Gridview launch . now you understand??